# Ionic 4 Unoptimised APK

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play-console

I am trying to pubblish my ionic 4 app to play store.

However I can't press the button **"START ROLL-OUT TO PRODUCTION"**, because of the warning **Unoptimised APK**.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow all the steps from this guide? https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/play-store

Comment: Hi Sergey. Yes I follow the steps.

Comment: I have the same issue with a package built with Ionic AppFlow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution** from https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/610 thanks to RobrechtVM

The steps are:

1. Launch Android Studio
2. Go To Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle,
   etc).
3. Select Android platform directory in your project
   (/platforms/android).
4. Wait till it finishes the Sync
5. Go to Build > Generate Sign Bundle
6. Complete sign data
7. Upload the .aab file(generated in path /platforms/android/outputs/ directory)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is just a warning the cordova team knows about and is about to fix in the near future

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/729

There is also a workaround with Android Studio explained in this issue.

I couldn't publish my app because of the missing content classification.
Make sure you have all checks green flagged. If so you should be able to proceed with the publication of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the link to the issue. I am downloding the Android Studio now to generate the new bundle format.

Answer (score 1):

I just make sure all the grey check is completed.
After I complete them all, suddenly there is a link that says I can now publish them. Eventhough I got that warning.

Just complete the grey check on the left bar until It becomes green checked.